# Cascading 2.0.0 job failing on hadoop FileNotFoundException job.split

Tags: hadoop, cascading

When i run my job on a larger dataset, lots of mappers / reducers fail causing the whole job to crash. Here's the error i see on many mappers:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/hadoop/.staging/job_201405050818_0001/job.split
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSClient.java:1933)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.<init>(DFSClient.java:1924)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:608)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:154)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:429)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:385)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:377)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1132)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Has anybody been able to solve this problem ? I see another human experiencing the same pain as me ([here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-mapreduce-user/201104.mbox/%3CBANLkTi=LF4H+t63qWWyCn7=kwSBdGF=x_w@mail.gmail.com%3E)), sadly he could not be saved in time.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of debugging, I found absolutely nothing useful in hadoop logs (as usual). Then i tried the following changes:

- Increasing the cluster size to 10
- Increase the failure limits :

  1. mapred.map.max.attempts=20
  2. mapred.reduce.max.attempts=20
  3. mapred.max.tracker.failures=20
  4. mapred.max.map.failures.percent=20
  5. mapred.max.reduce.failures.percent=20

I was able to run my cascading job on large amounts of data subsequently. It seems like a problem caused by cascading.